# How to produce a message digest?

Tags: padding, nonce

I've been trying this problem:

> Use the prototype function to hash message bit string into a length 16 message digest. Append (at the right end) the shortest nonce to the string (the spaces are just for easier reading)
>
> ```
> 1110 1011 0001 1011 0001 1100 1110 0111 1101 01
> ```
>
> that will produce a message digest that begins with five 0 bits at the left end. The nonce is to be appended before the message string is padded

I believe there is a typo that is append to the "right end" I think it should be left end.

What I been trying was pad the message with 10 zeroes to get

```
1110 1011 0001 1011 0001 1100 1110 0111 1101 0100 0000 0000
```

then I split this into the following matrix:

```
[1110 1011 0001 1011]
[0001 1100 1110 0111]
[1101 0100 0000 0000]
```

but I'm not sure what the "nonce" is supposed to come into this.

Any suggestions what I might be missing or doing wrong?